# Replace substring with whitespace in string

Tags: java, json, string

I have a string

```
String me = "I am ugly and not handsome."
```

I want to make it

```
I am ugly, not handsome.
```

So I need to replace *" and "* with *", "*. Supposedly I can do it with

```
String.replace(" and ", ", ")
```

However, it omits the whitespaces and looks for all instances of *`and`*. So this happens instead:

```
I am ugly, not h,dsome
```

I'm using this in a string parsing program. It's iterating over thousands of lines, so I want it to be speed efficient. I don't know if what I'm doing is "speed efficient" or what not if you have any other opinions I would appreciate it.
Sample file:

```
[and & , , , --- 1] (datetime)
[and & , , , --- 2] (datetime) - You are kind
[and & , , , --- 3] (datetime) - word1, word2 & wor&d3
[and & , , , --- 4] (Datetime) - word1, word2andword3, and word3
```

**For the sake of clarity on why I'm trying to achieve this and just in case someone has a better solution:**
The project I'm working on needs to parse this into a Json as so:

```
[
{
"message":"and & , , , --- 1",
"timestamp":"datetime",
"content":[]
},
{
"message":"and & , , , --- 2",
"timestamp":"datetime",
"content":[{"text":"You are kind"}]
},
{
"message":"and & , , , --- 3",
"timestamp":"datetime",
"content":[{"text":"word1"},{"text":"word2"},{"text":"wor&d3"}]
},
{
"message":"and & , , , --- 4",
"timestamp":"datetime",
"content":[{"text":"word1"},{"text":"word2andword3"},{"text":"word3"}]
},
]
```

Currently, I'm parsing it by iterating the file line by line and parsing the line into an entity. But I believe this will give me future problems when the format does not follow the desired parser format.

Comment: Tried using regex ?

Comment: just do a replace on "I am ugly " and "I am ugly, "

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behaviour. I get "I am ugly, not handsome." as result just as you want.

Comment: can you add more code details, " and ", will not omit space my default

Comment: use `String.replace(" \\s and \\s ", ", ")`

Comment: I was thinking of using regex. but i thought it would've taken longer to execute. I'm parsing thousands of lines. as for not being able to reproduce this behavior, that's strange. This has gone through multiple tests and every single time, it gives out "I am ugly, not h,dsome"

Comment: just to be clear, i'm trying to parse in this way because I think it's "efficient." not much of an expert in java though. if any of you have any idea how to easy parse thousands of lines of non-json data (let's say some fool wrote it in markdown) into json data, i'd appreciate your help. one of my main concerns is time complexity.

Comment: i know there are dependencies that can help in parsing, like markdown parser dependencies. But i want to do this without the help of other dependencies. Except ObjectMapper, if needed.

Comment: @ReiBrown Well, just running the line `System.out.println("I am ugly and not handsome.".replace(" and ", ", "));` should be enough of a test to see that replace isn't ignoring the spaces: https://ideone.com/PT8kLV

Comment: hmm. i'm using java 9. maybe in java 9? i don't know. i myself also believe that it should work that way, but it's not. I've tested it on that machine too. anyway, i'm gonna try regex first. then if it takes more time, i'll try this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with `String.replace` works fine and is faster than regex replaceAll.

```
@Test
public void testMirror() {
    String me = "I am ugly and not handsome.";
    String actual = me.replace(" and ", ", ");
    String expected = "I am ugly, not handsome.";
    Assert.assertEquals("hmm", expected, actual);
}
```

Somehow while copying in the editor, the leading and trailing spaces for `and` got lost perhaps.

---

It normally would be faster than regex

```
private static final Pattern AND_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s+\\band\\b");
...
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN .matcher(me);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, ",");
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    String changes = sb.toString();
```

However the regex can deal better with whitespace, and actually `replace(String, String)` is implemented with regex too. So having the pattern compiled only once
(a time intensive operation for complex patterns), might actually make the regex faster. The optimum would be using a non-regex Pattern:

```
private static final Pattern AND_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(" and ", Pattern.LITERAL);
...
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN .matcher(me);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, ", ");
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    String changes = sb.toString();
```

---

***The fastest might be:***

```
private static final Pattern AND_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(" and ", Pattern.LITERAL);
...
    String changes = PATTERN.matcher(me).replaceAll(", ");
```

Comment: hmm maybe so. but regarding speed, is it really faster than regex? because in my tests, iterating over thousands of files, it was exceeding the expected time execution.

Comment: I checked things out about String.replace and added two regex old-style solutions. The last one should be fastest. The first regex is correct too. The accepted answer might indeed be the overall fastest one.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringSpace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String me = "I am ugly and not handsome.";
        String changes = null ;

        Pattern whitespace = Pattern.compile("\\s\\band\\b");
        Matcher matcher = whitespace.matcher(me);
        while (matcher.find()){
            changes = matcher.replaceAll(",");
        }
        System.out.println(changes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of this but was afraid to implement it due to time complexity. But I'll surely try this out.

Answer (score 1):

try this, very simple

Input : I am ugly and not handsome.

```
String str = "I am ugly and not handsome.";
int i = 0;
i = str.IndexOf(" and");
str = str.Remove(i, " and".Length);
str = str.Insert(i, ",");
```

Output : I am ugly, not handsome.